# Suppress SBT eviction warnings

Tags: sbt, version, dependency-management, suppress-warnings, sbt-0.13

As of SBT 0.13.6, evictions are now warnings.

```
[warn] Scala version was updated by one of library dependencies:
[warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-library:(2.10.4, 2.10.1, 2.10.3, 2.10.0) -> 2.10.2
[warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.0 -> 2.10.4
[warn] To force scalaVersion, add the following:
[warn]  ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:(4.1.3, [4.1, 4.2)) -> 4.0.1
[warn]  * org.specs2:specs2_2.10:(1.12.3, 2.3.13) -> 2.4.2
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
```

How can I suppress these warnings?

Answer (score 7):

This should do it:

```
evictionWarningOptions in update := EvictionWarningOptions.default.withWarnTransitiveEvictions(false).withWarnDirectEvictions(false).withWarnScalaVersionEviction(false)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this? Can you provide more information?

Comment: @jpp E.g., lazy val myprj = Project(id = appName, base = file("."), settings     = Seq(scalaVersion := "2.11.5", ..., evictionWarningOptions in update := EvictionWarningOptions.default.withWarnTransitiveEvictions(false).withWarnDirectEvictions(false).withWarnScalaVersionEviction(false)))

Comment: I get `error: not found: value evictionWarningOptions`. This is in a Play project, using sbt 0.13.7.